# One of my DisplayLink monitors only shows vertical stripes and cursor

Tags: display, dell, displaylink

I have my Dell G5 laptop running Ubuntu 21.04 connected to a Dell D6000 dock. I have a Lenovo monitor attached that works just fine, and an HP monitor that doesn't. It just has vertical stripes and my mouse cursor if I move it over there(as seen in photo). I can't move windows to this monitor. If I try, I will just see the mouse cursor.

[Heavily cropped photo because 2MB limit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzhoo.jpg)

Comment: Does the HP monitor work somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Update the firmware on your Dell D6000 dock. You can download the updater utility at [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/dell-universal-dock-d6000/drivers).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps change the resolution of the extended display to something lower or higher depending on what it is already. I had an issue with the refresh rate setting on my secondary monitor.

[image]